# C Comparison Types

Tags: c, types, char, int

```
int main(void) {
  int x = 0;
  int* p = &x;
  char* q = p;
  while (*p == *q) { //What happens here?
     x = x + 1;
  }
  printf(“%d\n”, x);
}
```

Well I have this simple program here. I am confused on how this works. I would be obliged if you can help me.

I have a test and would like to learn how this works. Thank you in advance.

**Q Pointer Question**

|----------------------------|
               0x00<-------------Q points here?
|----------------------------|
               0x00
|----------------------------|
               0x00
|----------------------------|
               0x00<-------------Q points here?
|----------------------------|

**So after x = x+1. Is it?**

|----------------------------|
               0x00<-------------0x01 here?
|----------------------------|
               0x00
|----------------------------|
               0x00
|----------------------------|
               0x00<-------------0x01 here?
|----------------------------|

Comment: @Jim Balter: [see on codepad](http://codepad.org/n5ICHMIJ)

Comment: What's your point? The behavior is undefined, so while it may do one thing on codepad (today), it might do something different tomorrow, or in other compilers and implementations.

Comment: @JimBalter: Uhhh..well it was on last years exam. So, I have to study it so if he puts a similar question, I will know the answer.

Comment: So flunk the instructor ... or give the correct answer: it's undefined behavior. Or did the question give details about the architecture that you have failed to provide here?

Comment: @JimBalter Could you elaborate in how far the behaviour is undefined? Converting to `char*` is legit, dereferencing that `char*` too, if I understand correctly. Whether you get the least significant, most significant or another byte is unspecified, but it's the lowest-addressed byte. If the width of `int` is larger than `CHAR_BIT + 1`, `x = x+1;` doesn't overflow before the values become unequal, so then I see no UB, only the value that is printed is implementation-dependent. Or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on endianness, but it's essentially:

```
while (x == ((char) x)) {
    ++x;
}
```

The loop will terminate once `((int) x) != ((int) lowest byte of x)`

Comment: @bluejamesbond Ah, I suppose that's because 1000000 will be interpreted as signed :).

Comment: 'it's essentially' -- Since the behavior is undefined, some implementations might happen to work like that. Others certainly won't.

Comment: Corbin and @chris: I have added to the question. Can you please help me with this part? Thank you.

Comment: @bluejamesbond The answer to your question is, as I've said, undefined ... it may be different on different implementations, even wildly different.

Comment: @bluejamesbond Your diagrams differ in which end of the number is incremented vs. which end q points to ... that's exactly what Corbin means by "it depends on endianness". You should google that term.

Answer (score 1):

First, `p` and `q` are dereferenced (via the *) to get the int and char they're pointing to. Then, the char is promoted to an int, and the values are compared for equality.

Comment: in that case, the second I add 1 to x, it will stop because `q` will be `0` while `p = 1`;

Comment: @bluejamesbond, They both point to `x`. The difference is that `q` is a  `char *`, which means that the value of `*q` depends, as Corbin says, on endianness.